# updated django from 1.4 to 1.5.1; now DeprecationWarning on setup_environ

Tags: python, django, updates, django-1.5

updated django from 1.4 to 1.5.1
now its throwing this:

> DeprecationWarning: The 'setup_environ' function is deprecated, you
>   likely need to update your 'manage.py'; please see the Django 1.4
>   release notes (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/).

First, I was already on v1.4 so why its showing this now? well..

manage.py already have this:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
```

but few apps using this:

```
from django.core.management import setup_environ
from mysite import settings
setup_environ(settings)
```

if I comment the above code it throws an error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting
>   AUTH_USER_MODEL, but settings are not configured. You must either
>   define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
>   settings.configure() before accessing settings.

so, I called 'settings.configure' and replaced the above code with:

```
from django.conf import settings
from mysite import settings as mysettings
settings.configure(mysettings, DEBUG=True)
```

but it's still throwing as error!

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LOGGING_CONFIG'

basically 'setup_environ' is working but with the DeprecationWarning, how can I get ride of it?
Obviously, I red the release notes 1.4 but can't figure this out..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I end up adding:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
```

not only to my manage.py file, but also in the app files where I was calling 'setup_environ'.
So, I replace this code:

```
from django.core.management import setup_environ
from mysite import settings
setup_environ(settings)
```

with:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
```

No DeprecationWarning  and seems like its working!